# fill formulaes across using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write a code that adds numbers from cells in a column and repeat until there are no values in the following columns.

I can get the code to sum the first column and place the result under the last value, but can't get it to continue across the row.

```
   Sub Button1_Click()

   Range("b1").Select
   ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
   Range("b1").Select
   ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
   Dim vStartRow As Integer
   vStartRow = 2
   Dim vEndRow As Integer
   vEndRow = ActiveCell.Row
   Cells(vEndRow + 1, 2).Formula = "=sum(b" & vStartRow & ":b" &              
   vEndRow & ")"
   End Sub
```

e.g.

```
        Sales1  Sales2  Sales3  Sales4
Thi     15      1       78      2
Helena  23      3       15      3
Gerard  30      5       66      4
Tom     18      16      20      5
Harry   20      27      28      6
Pete    16      36      45      7
Sam     45      41      16      8
John    27      20      23      9
Kerry   16      65      96      10
Fred    1       2       3       11
Sue     4       5       6       12
Dave    7       8       9       13
Emma    10      11      12      14
       232
```

The code must continue to run and do a sum, until there are no values in the next column. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the code determine the amount of columns used, and loop through them, or set them manually.

This is an example, where excel will automatically count the columns.
Then it will count the amount of people, assuming that you want the totals on the same row.
If you want to count the rows of every column individually, just move the `RowLenght` to the first part of the loop, and change the `1` to `i`.

I've tried to incorporate your original idea as much as possible, and we have two variables that we can set manually `StartRow` and `StartColumn`.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim ColumnLenght As Long, RowLenght As Long, i As Long, ColumnLetter As String, StartRow As Long, StartColumn As Long

ColumnLenght = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
RowLenght = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
StartRow = 2
StartColumn = 2

For i = StartColumn To ColumnLenght
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
    Cells(RowLenght + 1, i).Formula = "=sum(" & ColumnLetter & StartRow & ":" & ColumnLetter & RowLenght & ")"
Next i

End Sub
```

**Here is the code in action:**

[image: Example]